# profile object permissions for a detail record

Tags: custom-object, administration, profile, data, master-detail

When readng through trailhead salesforce I came across a line which I am unable to digest. The line says - "You can’t set profile object permissions for a detail record". What does this mean? In my free developer org, I went to setup->profile->any one profile->Custom object permission, Is that where I should be looking to understand this?

Reference -> https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/force_com_admin_beginner/data_modeling/object_relationships

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to objects which are related by the master detail relationship. In case of such relationships we have two objects - parent ( usually referred as Master) and child(referred as detail). When a master detail relationship is created, all the security features that are applied on the parent(Master) object are inherited by the child(Detail) object. For eg: if a user has certain set of permissions on parent object then he will have same set of permissions on child object. You cannot specify the permissions for child object.

I hope I am able to clarify your question.

**UPDATE**:

I think I figured out what this statement meant. I think it meant - **The permissions for being able to create, edit or delete a child record depends on permissions set on master object.**

If you have "**read**" permissions on Master object, you can go ahead and set **read**, **create**, **edit** and **delete** permissions on Child object.

If you **dont** give "**read**" permissions on Master object, then you wont be able to give any permissions on child object.

I tried below in my dev org.

**Scenario 1:**
I had **read** permissions on Master object and **read**,
    **create**, **edit** and **delete** on child object.

- When i removed **read** permissions on master    object, all
  permissions on child object were automatically removed.

**Scenario 2:**

Now i tried giving read and create permissions on child object, with no permissions on master object.

- I was expecting SFDC to throw an error, but surprisingly it allowed
  me to do that. ***But what it also did was, it automatically enabled
  read permissions on Master object.***

Thus, from the above, i can say, what salesforce states is correct. You need to provide atleast read permission on master object for being able to set permission on child object.(Which indirectly means- "***You can’t set profile object permissions for a detail record.***")

Comment: I think your answer coincides more with the sharing rules bullet point "The detail record inherits sharing rules from the master record."

Comment: When I create a new master object I do not set any permissions on profile level. I created a child object and a master-detail field on child object. I am unable to understand why I am not able to edit Custom Object Permissions for any profile

Comment: @JennyB you are correct. I probably misunderstood the question. I was thinking about permission granted by sharing  rules and ownership.

Comment: @Rdvsm - are you working on standard profile??

Comment: No , custom profile. It is called Marketing in free developer edition

Comment: Sorry its not custom. I guess these are already existing profiles. We can't modify already existing profiles?

Comment: Correct. You will have to clone an existing profile and then modify it as per your needs.

Comment: Please see the edit. I am trying to understand what permission does child object inherit from master object.

Comment: Updated the answer with my view on the statement made by SFDC - You can’t set profile object permissions for a detail record

Comment: Nice update and that is a lot closer although I still struggle with the word "can't".

Comment: To put in other words - You cant set any profile permission on child object if you have not set read permission on Master object. If you do that, read permission on Master object is set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if they mean that you can't set the profile object permission for the master field on the detail record. I am looking at a Profile at a Custom Object that is the detail (Line Items) to the Master record Invoice. I cannot modify the access to the field that relates to the Master Invoice as seen in this image, the field is grayed out and checked since it is required by default as noted in the Trailhead unit.

> This creates a special type of relationship between two objects (the
>   child, or detail) and another object (the parent, or master). This
>   type of relationship closely links objects together such that the
>   master record controls certain behaviors of the detail and subdetail
>   record. In a master-detail relationship, the ownership and sharing of
>   detail records are determined by the master record, and when you
>   delete the master record, all of its detail records are automatically
>   deleted along with it. Master-detail relationship fields are always
>   required on detail records.

It might also be an error, you should submit your question as feedback on Trailhead.

Added 2 screenshots -> one with and one without the enhanced profile editor. (Click on Setup -> Profiles -> One of your Custom Profiles -> Object Settings or Scroll Down to Custom Object Permissions... Also note that I have Enabled Enhanced Profile User Interface under Setup -> User Interface)

[image: Enhanced Profile Editor]
[image: Regular Profile Editor]

Comment: isn't this true for any 'required' field in the database, not just the MD fields which too are required at the db level. Thanks

Comment: @Stygon yes but it mentions it specifically in the Trailhead Unit that it's required by default. So I'm just guessing at what they might have been referring to, could just be a mistake might be worth submitting it as feedback.

Comment: Yup second that.

Comment: Where do you get this screen? How do you navigate to this setting shown in the screen shot?

Comment: I agree this could be a mistake.

Comment: @Rdvsm Click on Setup -> Profiles -> One of your Custom Profiles -> Object Settings... Also note that I have Enabled Enhanced Profile User Interface under Setup -> User Interface

Comment: @JennyB - Do you have any comments on the screen shot I posted in my question?

Comment: @Rdvsm - that is the old profile view and not the enhanced view. That image is what I would understand the "Object Permissions" to be but not sure exactly what they meant on Trailhead, could be an error or maybe they meant something else.

Comment: Ok, I am just trying to understand that , what limitation(in terms of permission, security etc) child object has if it is in association with a Master object.

Comment: @Rdvsm basically the sharing rules are inherited by the child record. If you go to Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings you will see that a detail object is controlled by the parent.

Comment: Correct. I see that. I hope statement made in trailhead means the same.

Comment: I tried to analyse the statement and came up with an updated answer. So i take my words back. I think it is not a mistake and the statement made by SFDC is correct - You can’t set profile object permissions for a detail record